# Can't find where is the segmentation fault in C program

Tags: c, string

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char a[1000000];
    int i,j;
    int arr[1000000];
    gets(a);
    unsigned long int len=strlen(a);
    if(len<1000000){
    for(i=0,j=len-1;i<len&&j>=0;i++,j--)
                   arr[j]=a[i]-'0';
    }
    return 0;


}
```

I am using this code to store the number entered through keyboard into an integer array.But it keeps giving me segmentation fault.I don't know where it is.Plus I've heard `gets()` isn't a good option,
But I don't know how to use the alternative way to do it. It seems to be a fairly simple code.
Can anyone point where memory is leaking and why?
I have used the debugger on Code::Blocks,the call stack is empty.

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: `@user93353` Yes,won't show anything in the call stack

Comment: `len=strlen(a);` undefined behavior

Comment: 1) use a better debugger. 2) strlen(a) will never be >=1000000 because that would mean the terminating `\0` is beyond the end of the array

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I don't think it is UB unless Arjun is giving an input >= 1000000 characters. `gets` properly null terminates if it has enough buffer for the input and the null terminating character. And H2CO3 raised a good point on stack size.

Comment: "Can't find where is the segmentation fault in C program" - then use a debugger. And `char a[1000000];` **twice** will quickly exhaust the stack if you are on Windows (where the stack size is 1MB).

Comment: 3) gets is deprecated. 4) if gets returns null, the buffer you send it is unmodified (so in this example it would be undefined behaviour)

Comment: @Dave I am debugging on Code Blocks

Comment: I have used the debugger on Code::Blocks,the call stack is empty.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan and Dave - There is very little practical reason to think that someone has typed beyond 1000000 characters and that's what is causing his problem. I think it's pretty safe to say that it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative to gets it's fgets:

```
fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your array `a` as follows:

```
char a[ 1000000 ] = { 0 };
```

The convention in C for strings is to have a NULL terminator. This ensures two things:

1. `a` does not take on values from a previous stack frame.
2. `a` has a NULL terminator at the end.

**Remark:**

1. Having an array of length 1 million will exhaust your call stack quite quickly.

**Consider** using a dynamic array to be more space efficient. You would need to read one byte at a time from `stdin` until `EOF` or new line is sent, implemented as follows:

```
for ( int byte = getchar(); byte != EOF && byte != '\n'; byte = getchar() ) {
  dynarray_Add( dynArray, byte );
}
```

... where `dynArray_Add` would be some function that adds a character to your array of characters and performs the appropriately doubling when the length has reached the capacity.

If you are unfamiliar with a dynamic array, read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array).

Answer (score 1):

You have placed two very large arrays on the stack.  It's unlikely that your process was launched with a large enough stack (over 5MB).  The arrays a and arr should be dynamically allocated using malloc() or calloc() and freed later using free().

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code. The most obvious is that you're allocating a huge amount of memory on the stack, which is a bad idea even if it isn't causing a problem in itself. You're also using an old, unsafe function (`gets`) and you're not doing appropriate error checking.

`fgets` is almost a drop-in replacement for `gets`, and it has better safety. Simply call it with `fgets( a, 1000000, stdin )`, and it will never overrun the size of your buffer. Check the return value against `NULL` and you won't have uninitialised memory issues. Use `malloc` to get memory and you won't have stack size issues (don't forget to `free`!). Finally, don't use `int`s for your loop when the length is stored as an `unsigned long`! In this case the size of the buffer means it can't be an infinite loop but it's still bad style (also I think you want `size_t` not `unsigned long` - They just happen to be the same on your system).

Comment: I'll also point out that you can replace `j` with `len-i-1`. And you could do the reverse in-place (so no need to have 2 arrays) if you swap each element and only iterate half way through.